# Does Expo/React-Native support Cookies and all the security rules around it?

Tags: react-native, cookies, expo

A typical web app would have to conform to rules regarding the cookies.  But for a mobile app in React-Native or whatever technology of choice that is NOT running a WebView, does it follow the same rules?

(i.e. Origin, CORS, etc)

Or it just bypasses it since it's low-level API calls.

Normally I'd use cookies for simple [session management rather than JWT (as noted by the rant)](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) but only on a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies are a bit unstable and there are a couple of issues mentioned in the official documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#known-issues-with-fetch-and-cookie-based-authentication)

With that said, CORS only matters on browser environments (I think not sure tho - not sure about webviews), JWT is highly preferred because it can be easily maintained.